# how to create a daily csv file from clould firestore data using dart and flutter?

Tags: firebase, csv, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am basically trying to generate a daily csv file from my firestore data, as it represent customers' orders. This csv file will no be used in the app, instead, I want to get a daily mail that should be sent in a specific time and contains csv file with its data (orders). what are the possible ways of doing so?
I am reading data in my app using this method

```
 Future<void> fetchOrders(String userId) async {
    try {
      final response = await ordersCollection
          .document(userId)
          .collection('user_orders')
          .getDocuments();
      List<Order> loadedOrders = [];
      final querySnapshot = response.documents;

      querySnapshot.forEach(
        (order) => loadedOrders.add(
          Order(
            id: order['id'],
            totalPrice: order['totalPrice'],
            orderedBooks: (order['orderedBooks'] as List<dynamic>)
                .map(
                  (cb) => CartItem(
                    id: cb['id'],
                    title: cb['title'],
                    quantity: cb['quantity'],
                    price: cb['price'],
                  ),
                )
                .toList(),
            date: DateTime.parse(order['date']),
            phoneNo: order['phoneNo'],
            building: order['building'],
            road: order['road'],
            block: order['block'],
            area: order['area'],
            notes: order['notes'],
          ),
        ),
      );
      _orders = loadedOrders.reversed.toList();
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (e) {
      throw e;
    }
  }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You will be able to generate a `csv` file in app, but for generating it and sending it by email automatically you will have to use an API or something like [Firebase Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to completely separate this kind of logic from your application.

Since you already use Firestore for saving your data you can also use other firebase tools to achieve what you want.

For sending data via email you can use Firebase Cloud Functions. [You can read more about this topic here](https://medium.com/@edigleyssonsilva/cloud-functions-for-firebase-sending-e-mail-1f2631d1022e).

For triggering a cloud function once a day or at a specific time you can use Firebase Schedule Functions. [You can read more about this topic here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions).

Comment: Thank you for your help! will try it out

Comment: Okay. If this isn't the way you want to go please specify in your question why it isn't. Otherwise don't forget to mark the answer as accepted :)

Comment: yeah sure, but let me read it carefully to know if it fits my needs, if so, I will sure accept your answer ;)