# Export a firebase collection as CSV from a flutter app and download the file in mobile

Tags: android, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to download a collection 'user' from cloud fire store in my android application in the CSV format. The android application is built using flutter. I tried to google the topic, but could not get a straightforward solution.

I would be glad if anyone can give me some direction.

Thanks
Regards
Gourab

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5tMX.png)

Comment: You want to export a Firebase Collection as a CSV so you can use the collection data inside a mobile app without calling Firebase? or you want your users to be able to download a CSV file from the Flutter app and the data is coming from Firebase?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63414639/how-to-create-a-daily-csv-file-from-clould-firestore-data-using-dart-and-flutter) might help you.

Comment: @RomanJaquez : I want to have a download data button from where the information of a  collection can be downloaded from firebase and saved in the android application.